# How to retrieve results from generated from subquery

Tags: sql, select

For example:

```
SELECT tb1.column1, tb1.column2
FROM table1 AS tb1
WHERE tb1.column1 = (SELECT tb2.column2 FROM table2 As tb2)
```

But...there may be more than one result from the subquery.  If there are 3 results come from subquery, how can I handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `IN` on this.

`IN` can handle multiple values while `=` can hold only one.

```
SELECT tb1.column1, tb1.column2
FROM table1 AS tb1
WHERE tb1.column1 IN (SELECT tb2.column2 FROM table2 As tb2)
```

or the alternative way is to use `JOIN` which is more preferred,

```
SELECT  DISTINCT tb1.column1, tb1.column2
FROM    table1 AS tb1
        INNER JOIN table2 b
            ON tb1.column1 = b.column2
```

Comment: @user2218255 what do you mean by 2 results from the inner select?

Comment: @downvoter i don't care if you have downvoted this answer without leaving any comment. I was wondering what's wrong with this. Anyway happy downvoting :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `in` rather than `=`:

```
SELECT tb1.column1, tb1.column2
FROM table1 AS tb1
WHERE tb1.column1 in (SELECT tb2.column2 FROM table2 As tb2)
```

Comment: @user2218255 and that is why you use `in` instead of `=`.